# Как можно программно обновлять своё приложение на android?

Tags: android

Добрый вечер, возник вопрос как сделать чтобы своё готовое android приложение установленное на машине пользователя могло обновляться если я дополнил интерфейс или устранил баг и т д, как это прописать в коде ?

Comment: Я вообще не понял о чем вы спросили ) Даже интересно что конкретно Вы имеете ввиду

Comment: @RomanNovoselov, скорее всего автор имеет ввиду обновление своего же приложения, без участия play market. Есть такие приложения, которые сами себя обновляют

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Стандартными средствами и без рута - никак.

Обычно это происходит так: вы выкладываете новую версию приложения в маркет, девайс юзера через маркет по расписанию (силами маркета, т.е. без вашего участия) проверяет все установленные приложения на предмет наличия обновлений и, если у юзера поставлены соответствующие настройки в маркете, маркет сам установит обновление

---

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9045884/3212712), если у вы программно скачаете новый apk, у коего версия больше версии текущего и идентичные пакет и сертификат, то вы можете запустить системный Intent на обновление приложения так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(pathToApk));
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Далее юзер должен будет, по идее, подтвердить установку обновления.

---

Если девайс рутован, то можно вот [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15085540/3212712) запустить установку apk через систему без участия юзера:

```
public static void installNewApk()
{
    try
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "pm install -r /mnt/internal/Download/fp.apk"});
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        System.out.println("no root");
    }
}
```

---

Реализовать же логику запуска этого интента/команды можно примерно так:

1. При первом запуске приложения запишите во внутренние ресурсы (sharedPrefereneces) номер версии.
2. С к-л переодичностью проверяйте есть ли у вас где-то на к-л сервере новая версия.
3. Если да - скачивайте apk и по завершении запускайте интент/команду.

Comment: Мне нужно обойтись без маркета, а как само обновление происходит старое удаляется а новое устанавливается и если так то можно сделать проверку по номер версии приложения скажем была 1 стала 2 надо скачать и установить понятно что так должна рассуждать и проверять сама программа а не пользователь?

Comment: @VargSieg, дополнил ответ, хотя до сих пор не уверен, что я понял вашу задачу.

Comment: Всё отлично то что нужно )

Comment: Я так понимаю, что при выходе новой версии скачивался apk с "сервера", с позволения юзера, и устанавливалась.

Comment: @ВладимирSeos-Lab, если нет рута, то да - запускаем интент и юзер подтверждает установку. Если есть рут - можно поставить молча. В любом случае файл уже должен быть скачан. Скачать можно и не спрашивая юзера, в фоне, молча.

Comment: На самом деле есть простой вариант, как это сделать. Вы в приложении навязываете сервис, типо GCM, как только обновляете или исправляете баг, сервер отсылает сообщения на все установленные апки, и тогда уже можете в коде рализовать что угодно, чтоб не навязывать и сделать это правильно, показать пользователю что изменилось в новой версии и дать ссылку на ЛЮБОЙ магазин для загрузки свежей версии, но по сути это и делает стандартная консоль Google, хотя не на всех устройствах корректно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добрый день посоветуйте пожалуйста как на сервере можно сверять номер версии. На сервере лежит готовый apk файл то с чем можно у него свериться так это с его именем или с размером что не вариант ?

Comment: @VargSieg Ну, можно и в название номер вставить. А можно php скрипт написать, возвращающий версию. Или файлик с ней текстовый положить. И ещё множество способов

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  а как с помощь java можно вернуть номер версии не замачиваясь на PHP ?

Comment: @VargSieg, сложо что-то сказать не зная как вы собираетесь реализовывать. Можете просто в свободный доступ выложить txt файл на DropBox, написать в него номер версии и качать его в приложении. Прочитайте его и получите номер версии.

Comment: @VargSieg, добрый. Я не умею в линукс и сокеты

Comment: @ЮрийСПб понял извините за беспокойство.