# Android: заставить приложение обновить само себя

Tags: android

Нужно сделать так, чтобы приложение могло обновлять само себя. На некоторых форумах в интернете писали, что этот код сработает:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Но нужно так, чтобы приложение обновлялось на заднем фоне, без спроса пользователя. Максимум - уведомление, нотификация. Никаких хитростей я выдумать не пытаюсь. Всё заключается в том, что телефон играет роль веб-сервера.

Comment: Таким образом без спроса пользователя не получится, поскольку установку производит Программа установки пакета. Но можно попробовать другим способом(как это делается при подключении через adb c компьютера): используя `pm install /path_to_sdcard/download/app.apk`

Comment: @Ziens, а если ссимулировать нажатие на экране на кнопку Установить?..

Comment: Лично я не знаю такого способа. У вас root на устройстве имеется?

Comment: Нет. Но рутануть могу.

Comment: Вот ещё похожий вопрос с полезной инфой: [тык](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543222/17609)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так, но нужен root

```
    try {  
      Process install = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su\n");   
      DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(install.getOutputStream());
      os.writeBytes("pm install /mnt/sdcard/download/app.apk\n"); 
      os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
      os.flush();
      install.waitFor();

      if (install.exitValue() == 0) {  
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }  
      else {  
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure. Exit code: "+String.valueOf(install.exitValue()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

  }
  catch (InterruptedException e) {  
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (IOException e) {  
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Или так:

```
public static void InstallAPK(String filename){
    File file = new File(filename); 
    if(file.exists()){
        try {   
            String command;
            command = "adb install -r " + filename;
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", command });
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
  }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871570/install-unistall-from-shell-command-in-android
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926274/install-android-apk-without-prompt

Comment: Точно работает?)

Comment: @L'Esperanza Ну проверьте)

Comment: Жаль очень не скоро смогу проверить). Приложение очень большое, пока много багов, сейчас чищу. Если что-то не так пойдёт - напишу вам.

Comment: А после обновления (устнановки по вашему второму варианту) приложение перезапустится или мне придётся самому как-то Activity открывать?

Comment: @L'Esperanza скорее всего придется в ручную перезапускать, так как pm остановит приложение.

Comment: а можно успеть сразу задать команду запуска приложения (запуска основной Activity)?

Comment: @L'Esperanza Можно дописать `am start -n com.package.name/.ActivityName`

Comment: то есть `...new String[]{"su", "-c", command, "am", "start", "-n com.package.name/.ActivityName"}...`?

Comment: `new String[]{"su", "-c", commandPM, "&&", commandAM}`, где commandAM = am start -n com.package.name/.ActivityName

Comment: очень помогли, спасибо. Постараюсь поскорее проверить своё приложение, как только всё доделаю.