# Android: Error running exec(). su, -c, adb install

Tags: java, android

Есть следующий код:

```
Process i7 = null;
try {
    i7 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "adb install -r " + i5.getPath()});
    i7.waitFor();
} finally {
    if (i7 != null) {
        i7.getErrorStream().close();
        i7.getInputStream().close();
        i7.getOutputStream().close();
    }
}
```

Почему вылетает исключение?

> 10-03 16:10:24.801: E/(2446): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su, -c, adb install -r /data/user/0/camera/files/m.apk] Working Directory: null Environment: null

Comment: а другие команды SU выполняются? Например, чтение из файла в системной папке?

Comment: @metalurgus, Как это сделать? Дайте код я скажу работает или нет. Я не умею, к сожалению, это делать.

Comment: Вы взялись за слишком сложную задачу сходу. Я использую эту библиотеку https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser. Использую так: `Shell.SU.available()` - проверка и запрос рут прав. `Shell.SU.run("su .........");`

Comment: Кроме того, вы пытаетесь выполнить команду ADB на самом телефоне, у вас, я уверен, на телефоне не установлен ADB

Comment: @metalurgus, Это не только телефон, но и эмулятор на Android Eclipse.

Comment: Значения не имеет. Android система. Вы в нее установили ADB?

Comment: Как? *(11 символов нужно)*

Comment: "Как" - это не ответ

Comment: @metalurgus, Не знаю установлена она или нет. Спрашиваю как она устанавливается. Может она и есть.

Comment: никак не устанавливается. Это утилита для компьютера, а не для Andorid

Comment: @metalurgus, А вспомнил, есть на компьютере adb. "device attached" пишет.

Comment: @metalurgus, попробовал `adb install C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\gen.apk`: Success.

Comment: ок. Что вы хотите сделать вообще?

Comment: @metalurgus, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572816/26009

Comment: попробуйте лучше первый вариант из ответа, второй выглядит крайне сомнительно

Comment: @metalurgus, один в один та же самая ошибка. Я думаю, что что-то не так здесь: `Working Directory: null Environment: null`. Может рабочую директорию как-то задать сначала надо?

Comment: я использую библиотеку, на которую дал ссылку, там ничего не надо точно выставлять

Comment: @metalurgus, а можно без библиотек обойтись? Я не знаю как её в Eclipse импортировать. Мне просто желательно на существующих базовых классах всё сделать.

Comment: понятия не имею, как без нее обойтись. Но тот факт, что вы пользуетесь Eclipse сам по себе уже очень плох. Вы прям как живой динозавр...

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, чтобы выполнять команду `su` нужны root права.

Во-вторых, некорректно написана команда. Через `adb` я вообще не вижу смысла что-то делать. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575080/android-runtime-getruntime-execsu-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0-sleep-wait-delay/575196?noredirect=1#comment759828_575196) всё описано.