# Android: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su") - команда sleep / wait / delay

Tags: android, runtime, su

Есть следующий код:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su" + "\n");
OutputStream i8 = p.getOutputStream();
i8.write(("pm install " + myApkFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\n" + "reboot" + "\n" + "exit" + "\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
i8.flush();
p.waitFor();
```

Он устанавливает приложение. Но есть проблема. Приложение не успевает установиться, как сразу выполняется команда `reboot`, перезагружающая телефон. Было бы неплохо, если сначала выполнить установку приложения `"pm install ..."`, подождать `p.waitFor();`, а затем `"reboot"`, но не тут то было. Приложение таким способом обновляется, то есть заменяет само себя на новое приложение (`myApkFile`). Если я сделаю сначала `"pm install ..."`, потом `p.waitFor();`, а только потом `"reboot"`, то ничего из этого не выйдет. Если приложение заменяется, то все потоки, `Activity`, `Service`, `Receiver`ы и так далее - будут прерваны. Таким образом, команда `"reboot"` так же будет недостижима (unreachable code).

Теперь вопрос. Есть ли возможность выполнить что-то наподобие следующего скрипта для `su`:

```
pm install myApkFile.apk
sleep(30 секунд)
reboot
exit
```

Можно ли как-то эту 30-секундную задержку поставить? Думаю, за такое время телефон успеет установить приложение, а потом перезагрузиться.

---

Команда `"reboot"` перезагрузки телефона нужна обязательно, так как есть некоторые `Service`, которые запускаются только от `BroadcastReceiver`, активирующегося при помощи `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />`.

Comment: Что вам мешает после установки запустить службу напрямую?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, как приложение запустит само себя после установки?

Comment: А как вы установку-то запускаете?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в смысле как? Через `Runtime...exec("su")...pm install myAPK.apk...`. В вопросе же всё написано.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
pm install myApkFile.apk
sleep 30
reboot
exit
```

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, да. *(Вы сможете принять свой ответ через 11 часов)*

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!