# Как программно запустить установку apk после скачивания?

Tags: javascript, android

Всем привет.

Есть ли возможность запустить только что скаченный `.apk` файл автоматически (что бы показать пользователю окно установки)?

Суть вот в чем: имеется **HTML + JS** страничка на которой представлено 10 программ, пользователь напротив нужной программы нажимает "скачать", скачивается `.apk` файл. Как сделать так, что бы после скачивания программа сразу же предоставляла пользователю окно (как в плеймаркете) с информацией о приложении и кнопкой установить?

Я такое видел на нативных приложениях, есть ли возможность это сделать с браузера? Если нет, то я могу собрать эту страничку **HTML + JS** в нативный `.apk` файл, что нужно будет сделать в таком случае?

Буду очень благодарен за любой ответ!

Comment: Если из .apk то интент кинуть с путём к файлу. Из js врядли получится,  но я не специалист.

Comment: Интенеты можно запускать - https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents. А вот так, чтобы именно установку запускать - хз. Тут надо путь до файла скаченного на телефон иметь. Если можете его получить как-то - то вот тут смотрите какой интент надо запустить: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543222/17609