# Программное самообновление приложение на андроид MAUI C#

Tags: c#, android, maui

Делаю приложение на андроид, которое пока довольно бурно развивается. Круг пользователей где то человек 15 знакомых. Сейчас новые версии кидаю в тг, а там уже ручками все скачивают и устанавливают. Хочу сделать чтобы приложение автоматом устанавливало новую версию. Как её скачать я уже додуматься смог, теперь нужно запустить процесс установки. Как это сделать?

Comment: Судя по тому, что даже Сбер не смог этого сделать, вероятно, это невозможно или нетривиально, во всяком случае на нерутованном телефоне, или же нужны специфические разрешения как у стора. Процесс похож на установку одним приложением другого, что в рамках системы безопасности андройда разрешено только сторам. Само себя приложение переустановить не может, оно может только обновить свои некоторые ресурсы.

Comment: @aepot тогда ситуация получается крайне скверная. Однако тг как то может заставить одним нажатием на файл открыть его. Тут важно чтобы все происходило хотя бы в полуавтоматическом режиме, типо скачалось, потом высвечивается окошко андроидовское об установке и тут пользователь все еще ручками, но все таки этапов обновления меньше, устанавливает. Я уже пытался найти способ установки и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543221/Как-можно-программно-обновлять-своё-приложение-на-android) сказано что без рута вроде в "полуавтоматическом режиме" это возможно

Comment: Обновляйте через google play. Вы можете публиковать там свои версии в разные track'и. production, open testing, closed testing, internal testing. 
Есть еще firebase app distribution. 

Но и в своем приложении вы тоже можете сделать по крайней мере загрузку apk. И если очень надо далее автообновление через загрузку apk, но этот метод требует разрешения, гугл такое без причины не любит https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12085295

Comment: @aepot сбер забанен в маркете, врядли тут тот же случай.

Comment: @YuraIvanov нет, через google play нельзя. Как я знаю аккаунт разраба где то 25 долларов. Я не хочу вкладывать деньги и такое.